# It's correct to put locally created object into the std::map?

Tags: stack, copy-constructor, local-variables, stdmap

I have a `std::map` in `Driver` class, like this

```
std::map<int, dtp::driver_core::worker_record::WorkerRec> workers;
```

The class `WorkerRec` is a separate class and have a following constructor.

```
WorkerRec::WorkerRec(const std::shared_ptr<TaskCore> task, 
                     const std::string & hostname,
                     const std::string & pid):
    worker_task(task),
    worker_hostname(hostname),
    worker_pid(pid)
{
}
```

Also i have a member function in class `Driver`

```
int DriverCore::register_worker(const std::string & hostname, const std::string & pid)
{
.......................................................
.......................................................
WorkerRec w(task, hostname, pid);
workers[key] = w;
.......................................................
.......................................................
}
```

it's correct to put  local created object into std::map (`workers[key] = w`) or std::map copies the object and there is no problem ?

Answer (score 0):

There are no issues with the code as written.  The map will create a copy of w.

If you'd like to verify this for yourself, you can pass the workers map out of class into some other scope, call the WorkerRec destructor, and verify that the contents of the map remain valid.

You will only run into issues here if you have the map store pointers to locally owned data.